# Problem to build my React Native App in the Xcode 14

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode14

I'm the following problem, if someone can help me the solve?

Every I try run the project, show me the message build failed and show me this message in the log:

`Undefined symbol: _$s16FloatLiteralTypes013ExpressibleByaB0PTl

Undefined symbol: _$s18IntegerLiteralTypes013ExpressibleByaB0PTl

Undefined symbol: _$sBi32_WV

Undefined symbol: _$sSfs33_ExpressibleByBuiltinFloatLiteralsWP

Undefined symbol: _$sSfySfSdcfC

Undefined symbol: _$sSis35_ExpressibleByBuiltinIntegerLiteralsWP

Undefined symbol: _$ss25ExpressibleByFloatLiteralMp

Undefined symbol: _$ss25ExpressibleByFloatLiteralP05floatD0x0cD4TypeQz_tcfCTq

Undefined symbol: _$ss25ExpressibleByFloatLiteralP0cD4TypeAB_s01_ab7BuiltincD0Tn

Undefined symbol: _$ss27ExpressibleByIntegerLiteralMp

Undefined symbol: _$ss27ExpressibleByIntegerLiteralP07integerD0x0cD4TypeQz_tcfCTq

Undefined symbol: _$ss27ExpressibleByIntegerLiteralP0cD4TypeAB_s01_ab7BuiltincD0Tn

Undefined symbol: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftCoreFoundation

Undefined symbol: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftCoreGraphics

Undefined symbol: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftCoreImage

Undefined symbol: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftDarwin

Undefined symbol: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftDispatch

Undefined symbol: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftMetal

Undefined symbol: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftObjectiveC

Undefined symbol: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftQuartzCore

Undefined symbol: _*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftUIKit

Undefined symbol: __swift_stdlib_operatingSystemVersion

Undefined symbol: _swift_errorRetain

Undefined symbol: _swift_getForeignTypeMetadata

Undefined symbol: _swift_once

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, this happens beacause I had update my xCode for version 14.3 and I need change the architecture for Rosetta.

[Link for solution](https://sarunw.com/posts/open-using-rosetta-in-xcode-14-3/?fbclid=IwAR00Nr9yNTYR-YYC3xoL4MXde--w7Ct4aqe7JWMKYg1CVdLZOa3y_qbJ43g_aem_th_ASEs21o2PGScJ-Amjta-qoOyy1FLVfmOX8D6yQbjWv1Q2X2dh5i0I05-HdU8MMhHpBQ&mibextid=Zxz2cZ)